# sending values to server from a text box which have multiple values added on run time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following div in which I am adding the value through the function addAnswers() on run time Now I need to send these values over the server.(say I have 4 answers ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4..so I need to send them as 4 strings may be array of strings).please help..             
        
                  /div>                                                                                                function addAnswers(){                                                                                                       $('#answers').append('' + $('#answer').val() + ''); } 
Now when I add 4 answers to this div say ans1,ans2,ans3 and ans4 how do I send it to server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want to do, but sending a request to the server with jQuery is incredibly simple:

```
var s1 = 'string 1', s2 = 'string 2';
$.ajax({ url: 'server.url', data: 's1='+s1+'&s2='+s2 })
```

Comment: @herthor How do i get these strings as I have the following div      <div id="answers" >
   <input type="text" name="T2" size="20" id="answer" class="selector">
  </div><input type="button" value="+" name="B3" id="btnAnswer" onclick="addAnswers()">   On click of this button I am adding the answers.. function addAnswers(){ $('#answers').append('' + $('#answer').val() + ''); }

Comment: to get content of a div you can usedocument.getElementById('answers').innerHTML, but why don't you just use a regular form and submit it (even with ajax)?

Comment: @ Herhor I need to get all the answers as an array of string..and there are some more fields..

Comment: then this is a perfect example to use form! You can serialize form using jquery "params" function or some other plugin, e.g. check you my plugin (download and open index.html in browser) https://github.com/Herhor/formparams

Comment: @ Herhor  the no of answers is dynamic they could be any in number ..not only 4..thats why I am appending them on the text box using <p> i  the textbox..I can not use radio button.

Comment: in that case - don't append them to div, append them to a js array, e.g. var answers = []; answers.push(answer1); answers.push(answer2); and then - send the "answers" array...